# Moving table rows from one table to another using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got 2 tables that I'm trying to shift rows between in HTML using JavaScript, but I'm not having much luck at the moment.  I've tried plenty of solutions from here but none of them seem to be working for me at the moment!

Currently my HTML code is as per below

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden
}

.tab {
  float: left
}

.tab-btn {
  margin: 50px
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Manage Schools</h5>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="tab">
            <table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="table1">
              <tr>
                <th>School ID</th>
                <th>School Name</th>
                <th>Select</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>School A</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>School B</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>School C</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>School D</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>School E</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" "></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                    <td>School F</td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox "></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab tab-btn ">
                            <button>Add</button>
                            <button>Remove</button> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="tab ">
                            <table class="table table-sm table-hover " id="table2 ">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>School ID</th>
                                    <th>School Name</th>
                                    <th>Select</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, once a row has been shifted from table1 to the table2, it can then be removed from the table2 using the remove button.  Also being able to select multiple rows and moving them at the same time would be a huge advantage.

Any and all help with the JavaScript would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Where is your javascript code? What kind of solutions have you tried?

Comment: This will give you somewhere to start. https://jsfiddle.net/2fruschd/

Comment: There's a typo in your HTML, an extra double quote in `<input type="checkbox" ">`.